# Android Broadcast Receiver not starting (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

I've installed a broadcast receiver a few weeks ago in Java, now I want to do it in Kotlin, but unfortunately it does not work.

My Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.test"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.test.test.BootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My receiver:

```
package com.test.test

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED
import android.util.Log

class BootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(c: Context, intent: Intent?) {
        val action = intent?.action
        Log.d("ASD123123", "RECEIVED BOOT")
        val b = intent?.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)
        when (action) {
            ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED -> startWork(c)
        }
    }


    private fun startWork(context: Context) {
        Log.d("Test", "Test")
    }
}
```

When I reboot my device (Android 8.0.0) it does not start the service. Neither does it when I run

```
adb shell
am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
```

With

```
am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -n com.test.test/.Bootreceiver
```

it works though. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Checked with your code, it's working for me. Have you tried to open your app? You need to open it at least one time after installing

Answer (score 0):

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.startuptest.StartUpBootReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> // add this line
</intent-filter>
```

And in Broadcast receiver :

```
private fun startWork(context: Context) {
    Log.d("Test", "Test") // remove this and toast
    Toast(context,"Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Comment: I did, but nothing changed. Also tried to add android:priority="500"

Answer (score -1):

BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast receiver has been deprecated and no longer works.

Comment: Oh didn't know that. Is there anything which let my service start after boot?

Comment: Hm. When it was deprecated? Didn't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: Deprecated in favor of...?